# How do I start VS Code in terminal for a different distribution in WSL2?

Tags: linux, bash, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I've recently set a working copy of Ubuntu-20.04 WSL2 called Ubuntu-20.04-copy01 but I can't open/create files with vscode from the terminal, for example: `code main.rs` as with the original distribution.

The output of echo $PATH:

> /home/rogelio/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

The original distro output of the same command is

> /home/rogelio/anaconda3/bin:/home/rogelio/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Users/rogel/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:**/mnt/c/Users/rogel/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin**:/snap/bin

Would it be enough if I configure the .bashrc file of my copy of ubuntu to add /mnt/c/Users/rogel/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin?

I'm not sure if this would create conflicts.

I also changed the default distro used by wsl using `wsl --setdefault Ubuntu-20.04-copy01`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the WSL `init` process that runs when the instance is started is supposed to append the Windows path to the Linux `$PATH`.  It seems that either (a) that's not happening for some reason, or (b) something in your startup files is modifying it after the fact.

A few things to check:

- First, try launching that instance via `wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04-copy01 -e bash --noprofile --norc`.  Does `code .` work then?  Does `echo $PATH` look different than before? If so, then something in the startup files is to blame.  Look for anything in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (or any other startup files or referenced files) that might be modifying `$PATH`.
- If that's not it, then create or modify `/etc/wsl.conf` (with `sudo`) with the following settings:

  ```
  [Interop]
  appendWindowsPath=true
  ```

  That's supposed to be the default, but if it was set to false, that could cause the problem.  Regardless, let's just force it to `true` to be sure.

  You'll need to shut down the instance and restart for it to take effect, so:

  - Exit any shells running
  - From PowerShell or CMD:  `wsl --terminate Ubuntu-20.04-copy01`
  - Restart and check your $PATH and try `code .` again

To answer your follow-up question, yes, you *could* manually append `...VSCode/bin` to your `$PATH` in your startup files, but I would personally recommend fixing the core problem instead.  Being able to run Windows apps easily opens up a lot of possibilities.  For instance, you can run PowerShell commands via `powershell.exe` (e.g. `powershell.exe get-childitem HKCU:`).  You can even run the `wsl.exe` command from *within* WSL to use root-level commands with the need for a sudo password (e.g. `wsl.exe -u root service cron start`).

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I upvoted your answer but I need at least 15 reputation to publicly cast a vote.

Comment: No worries - When you get some more rep, the vote will end up counting retroactively.  Great to hear it worked!  Which part was it -- the shell config or the `wsl.conf`?